# How to get desired html from a contentEditable div

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

```js
$('#parent').on('input', function(){
  let a = $(this).html();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.parent{
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent' contentEditable>
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Place the cursor at the end of text and press `Enter`.
In console I'm expecting just `<br>` and not open and closed `div` tags.

Now, let's say I want a horizontal rule. Type `<hr>`
Result - `<div>&lt;hr&gt;</div>`

And of course when I place this value in a database (php, mysql) and getting this data back - there is no horizontal rule, just `<hr>` tag literally.

How to get desired html like this:

```
<br>  
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#parent').on('input', function() {
    // Retrieve the HTML-decoded content and log it
    let content = $('<textarea>')
      .html($(this).html())
      .text().trim()
      .replace(/<br><br>$/, '<br>');
    console.log(content);
  });

  $('#parent').on('keydown', function(e) {
    // Catch Enter key and insert <br>'s manually
    if (e.which === 13) {
      document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.parent {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent" class="parent" contenteditable>
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: See my last edited version. Also trimmed the leading/trailing newlines.

Comment: that's it. So maybe the question - what is the purpose at all of `contentEditable` attribute if one needs such a hacking code to get its html.

Comment: Well, you're not supposed to *write* HTML tags into it yourself. Any text you type will be considered as such (text) and therefore automatically be html-encoded, so I used a trick to decode it. And the double `<br>` is there because if there's only a single one, the cursor will not go to the next line.